# Where is the ideal place to ask a MATLAB question?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

For most cases the answer is either Stack Overflow or Cross Validated. But for my current [question](https://superuser.com/questions/997493/is-there-a-gui-way-to-copy-a-folders-path-in-matlab), neither of them seem suitable. Is SU the right place? I also see MATLAB in Area 51, but I'm not sure if that site is actually for asking questions, or discussing the proposal itself.

So I would appreciate any help on where to ask such a specific question.

Comment: Mathematica has its own SX site. Why shouldn't MATLAB?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[SuperUser](http://superuser.com) seems the right place. The question is quite a general software question and that doesn't go well on the other two sites mentioned.

SuperUser already has a MATLAB tag, so it seems to be the place to go.

---

There are [other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293432/245360) allowing questions related to MATLAB, but this specific question seems to fit best on SuperUser.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Patrick. I think what I had in mind when asking for the "best place", I was also considering the response time. SU is probably not followed by as many Matlab-ers as those 2 sites. See, the question still only has 6 views. So I wish I could somehow make SO or CV community aware of the question, that would yield much quick results :) Thanks,

Comment: Maybe post in some chat rooms on that site. Not much more to do.

Comment: If you use Twitter, Facebook and/or Google+ then you can also use the share button to let the people who follow you know that you have posted it.

Comment: I'm not very into social media, but I actually tried Patrick's suggestion, to promote the question in chat rooms. So it seems like the best solution for me. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @jeff how do you promote questions in chat rooms?

Comment: @CharlieParker I just paste the link there and explain the question a little, hoping anyone interested will see it.