# MATLAB questions in Mathematica, MathOverflow, Cross Validated, SuperUser, Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Do **Mathematica Stack Exchange**, **MathOverflow**, **Stack Overflow**, **Super User** and **Cross Validated Stack Exchange** accept **MATLAB** questions?

If not, could someone suggest good question and answers forums for **MATLAB** (specifically for communications - signal processing, fourier transformation,...)?

It would be great if we would have **MATLAB Stack Exchange**.

Comment: If you're going to abuse that many backticks, then no

Comment: @random, What do you mean?

Comment: `\`` is not the same as `"` and it certainly is not a substitute for marking words bold

Comment: Re the new site, see: [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974/307988)

Comment: StackOverflow accepts MatLab questions, they have the appropriate tag for "MatLab".

Comment: @MetaOverflow - Of course not every MatLab question is on topic at Stackoverflow, it still has to be within scope, just like every computer question isn't on topic at Superuser.

Comment: @Ramhound If his question is odd topic, it should __not even be__ on any Stack Exchange site

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer - What do you mean?

Comment: @Ramhound Blame auto correct. I meant "off topic" instead of "odd topic"

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer: A question being off-topic on SO doesn't mean it's off-topic everywhere else, or even that it has nothing to do with programming. I don't know much about MATLAB, but I would be surprised indeed if there were no questions about it that could be asked on SE that didn't actually have to do with practical problems unique to software development.

Answer (score 7):

- For **signal processing** questions involving MATLAB, see [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com).
- For **statistical questions** involving MATLAB, see [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).
- For MATLAB programming questions, see [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)

Mathematica is an entirely different product (by Wolfram), MATLAB questions don't belong on that site. MathOverflow is a site about mathematical research. Super User is for usage questions, not programming questions.

There is a proposal for [MATLAB site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106196/matlab), which does not get much attention.

Answer (score 2):

As a user of Stack Overflow, I know that we accept questions regarding MATLAB issues. You simply need to tag "MATLAB" with your question to get relevant assistance.

I haven't used Super User or Cross-Validated, but @Gerry has covered those.

As for creating a site specifically for MATLAB questions on the Stack Exchange network, I feel that it would not attract enough visitors, as MATLAB is only one programming language, and it is already accessible via other sites on the Stack Exchange network. However, that's just what I feel, and any opinions are welcome in the comments box.

If you want to support a proposal for a MATLAB-specific site, then visit this link on Area 51: [MATLAB proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106196/matlab)